# Don't encode json from php

Tags: php, android, json

I have 2 files php: connect.php and getsp.php. As follow:

**- Connect.php:**

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "thietbi";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
    mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'uft8'");
```

**- Getsp.php**

```
include "connect.php";
// mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
$page = $_GET['page'];
$idsp = 1;  
$space = 5;     
$limit = ($page - 1) * $space;      

$mangsanpham = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM sanpham WHERE idsanpham = $idsp LIMIT $limit,$space";       
$data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $tsp = $row['tensanpham'];
    $gsp = $row['giasanpham'];
    $hsp = $row['hinhanhsanpham'];
    $mtsp = $row['motasanpham'];
    $isp = $row['idsanpham']));

    array_push($mangsanpham, new Sanpham($id, $tsp, $gsp, $hsp, $mtsp, $isp));
}

echo json_encode($mangsanpham);

class Sanpham{
    function Sanpham($id, $tensp, $giasp, $hinhsp, $motasp, $idsanpham){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->tensp = $tensp;
        $this->giasp = $giasp;
        $this->hinhsp = $hinhsp;
        $this->motasp = $motasp;
        $this->idsanpham = $idsanpham;
    }
}
```

When I run file "Getsp.php", result is white blank page.

I replace getsp.php with content:

```
include "connect.php";
// mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
$page = $_GET['page'];
$idsp = 1;  
$space = 5;     
$limit = ($page - 1) * $space;      

$mangsanpham = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM sanpham WHERE idsanpham = $idsp LIMIT $limit,$space";       
$data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    array_push($mangsanpham, new Sanpham(
    $row['id'],
    $row['tensanpham'],
    $row['giasanpham'],
    $row['hinhanhsanpham'],
    $row['motasanpham'],
    $row['idsanpham']));
}

echo json_encode($mangsanpham);

class Sanpham{
    function Sanpham($id, $tensp, $giasp, $hinhsp, $motasp, $idsanpham){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->tensp = $tensp;
        $this->giasp = $giasp;
        $this->hinhsp = $hinhsp;
        $this->motasp = $motasp;
        $this->idsanpham = $idsanpham;
    }
}
```

The result is not. Where did I wrong? 
I tried 2 ways:

```
$json = json_encode($mangsanpham, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($json);
```

and

```
echo json_encode($mangsanpham);
```

The results are not encode JSON. Hope to get help from everyone!

Answer (score 2):

To use array_push, you have to declare first variable as array
i.e $mangsanpham = array();  //before while loop

Comment: I did that but not yet. What do I wrong? Help me, please!
Thank you!